# How to assign a value to each item inside an ordered list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, list, frontend

I'm trying to give a percent matching score like `90% Match` to each of my search results.

I haven't found any solutions to write a function in python that would do that so I was wondering if there's a way to create some Javascript code that would automatically assign a random value from 100 to 50% (in reverse order) to every items inside of an ordered list (which are my search results) based on the default order of the list (1,2,3,4..).

A quick example of the html:

```
<ol class="ordered-list">

   <li class="list-item"><\li>  <!-- This item represent the 1st result -->
   <li class="list-item"><\li>  <!-- 2nd result -->
   <li class="list-item"><\li>  <!-- 3rd result -->
   <li class="list-item"><\li>  <!-- 4th result -->

   <!-- Etc... -->

<\ol>
```

Now the final expected results should look to something like this:

```
- Title 1
  Description...
  *100% Match*

- Title 2
  Description...
  *92% Match*

- Title 3
  Description...
  *85% Match*

- Title 4
  Description...
  *56% Match*
```

Ps; The search results are not all manually added, they all come from a database and an index.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using any  one of these? Jquery/react

Comment: I'm not using React, but I'm definitly open to use Jquery if it can make this work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python's random library to achieve the random generation of the scores.

```
import random

results_size = 4
scores = random.sample(range(50, 101), results_size)
scores.sort(reverse=True)
print(scores)
```

Sample output:

```
[93, 73, 68, 50]
```

And then iterate the scores list and assign its current value to the current list element.

Comment: Thanks so much, the only problem is that I don't know exactly the number of results that I have since every queries are different. Can I do it without the `results_size` instance?

Comment: Can I ask what are you using to get the results?

Comment: Of course, I use Elasticsearch for indexing and a Postgresql database!

Comment: I think you could use the len(search_results) method to get the number of results.

Comment: Can we continue the conversation in private? I have some infos and lines that I could share more easily with you.

Answer (score 0):

This part is for generating a random number within the range of 75 - 100:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

This part is the example of the code that you can use, you can generate the `<li>` items as many as the number of rows you got from the database by changing the `itemLength` and you can change the content of the list item by replacing `randomInt` in `listItem.appendChild(randomInt)` into the description you would like to put in there.

```
<body>
    <ol id="listObject">

    </ol>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var orderedList = document.getElementById("listObject");
    var itemLength = 5; //REPLACE THIS WITH THE LENGTH OF THE ITEM LIST

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    var listItem; var randomInt;

    for (var i = 0; i < itemLength; i++){

        listItem = document.createElement("LI");
        randomInt = document.createTextNode(getRandomInt(50, 100).toString() + "%");
        listItem.appendChild(randomInt);
        orderedList.appendChild(listItem);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already have a list item and the number of results come from the search query. Here's my html for the search results:

Comment: `  <div>
{% if  page_obj.object_list %}
                <ol class="row top20" id="my_list">

        {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

<li class="list-item">
   <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
        <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
          <h5>{{ result.object.destination }}</h5>

     <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
     </a>

   </div>
</li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ol>
            </div>
        `

Comment: Is there a way to change the code so that It works with this?

Comment: are those code used for generating the `<li>` ? then maybe you can just edit the content of the tag that shows the percentage using javascript.

Comment: Yes, basically if there's no results found for a given query, the list items won't show up. And could you include an example of the code that would work by editing the content of the tag?